# @ExceptionHandler only working with Exception.class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation on one of my controllers, but if I use any Exception type other than `Exception.class`, the page returns the message

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Here's my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foobar")
public class TodayInHistoryController {

@Autowired(required = true)
private TodayInHistoryService service;

private static final String DATE_FMT = "yyyyMMdd";

/**
 * 
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HistoryContent getTodayInHistory(
    @RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) Date date) {
if (date != null)
    return service.getHistoryContent(date);

return service.getHistoryContent();
}

/**
 * Binds URL arguments to their correct object representation.
 * 
 * @param binder
 */
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
// Date object binder
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FMT);
binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
    dateFormat, false));
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 */

// If I change the value param of the annotation to Exception.class it works fine...
@ExceptionHandler(NumberFormatException.class)
public ModelAndView handleParseException(Exception ex) {
    // create and populate Map to hold error data
Map<String, String> errorData = new HashMap<String, String>();
errorData.put("errorMessage","Formatting error occurred");
errorData.put("errorDetails", "None");

// create and return ModelAndView
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
mv.addAllObjects(errorData);

    return mv;
}
}
```

Here's my spring config (what's relevant)

```
@Configuration
@Import(ServicesConfig.class)
@ImportResource({ "classpath:applicationContext-security.xml",
"classpath:dataSources.xml" })
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.controller")
public class WebConfig {

@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver() {
ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
resolver.setIgnoreAcceptHeader(true);
resolver.setDefaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
resolver.setFavorPathExtension(true);
resolver.setOrder(1);

// setup mediaTypes
Map<String, String> mediaTypes = new HashMap<String, String>();
mediaTypes.put("json", "application/json");
mediaTypes.put("xml", "application/xml");
resolver.setMediaTypes(mediaTypes);

// setup defaultViews
List<View> defaultViews = new ArrayList<View>();
defaultViews.add(jsonView());
defaultViews.add(xmlView());
resolver.setDefaultViews(defaultViews);

return resolver;
}

@Bean
public View jsonView() {
return new MappingJacksonJsonView();
}

@Bean
public View xmlView() {
return new MarshallingView(new CastorMarshaller());
}
}
```

Comment: the message you're getting usually means that not all required parameters are present, but in your case the parameter is optional so I guess that there was an error converting the parameter other than `NumberFormatException`. Can you post your request url and `CustomDateEditor`?

Comment: I was actually passing a value to the URL that is not in the correct format on purpose in order to test Exception handling.  If I do this with Exception.class as the value then it works as expected.  An example incorrect URL would be /services/foobar?date=asdf . The service works fine with a correctly formatted date (i.e /services/foobar?date=20120401)

Comment: As far as the CustomDateEditor is concerned, is that needed here since I'm using an @InitBinder annotated method?

Comment: hah, forgot that CustomDateEditor is spring class ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that spring tries to convert date string to `Date` and fails. When that happens `TypeMismatchException` (which wraps `IllegalArgumentException`, which in turn wraps `ParseException`) is thrown and you should handle that instead of  `NumberFormatException`.

When you changed the exception class to `Exception` it got handled, as `TypeMismatchException` extends `Exception`.

A tip: if you're using any logging framework, try turning debug logging on for spring mvc classes, it can clear things up a lot.

For example put something like this in your lo4j.propeties:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.servlet=DEBUG
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I don't understand why the @ ExceptionHandler method is even called if the actual Exception is TypeMismatchException and not NumberFormatException.  Shouldn't the ExceptionHandler be passed over in this case instead of giving the 'syntactically incorrect' error?  I thought @ ExceptionHandler has the value attribute in order to only handle a subset of Exceptions.

Comment: It is passed over - the page and message you get is a default spring error page for `TypeMismatchError` (and many others), unless you have changed it.